# Is there a way that I can center a grid in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

My idea is to make a GUI with a grid and I want that the grid it self to be centered in the window.

```
root = Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
telaInicial = Frame(root)

botaoNovoAluno = Button(telaInicial, text = "Novo aluno", padx = 5, pady = 5)
botaoEliminarAluno = Button(telaInicial, text = "Eliminar aluno", padx = 5, pady = 5)
botaoAvaliacaoAluno = Button(telaInicial, text = "Avaliaçao aluno", padx = 5, pady = 5)
botaoVerDados = Button(telaInicial, text = "Ver dados", padx = 5, pady = 5)

botaoNovoAluno.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
botaoEliminarAluno.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
botaoAvaliacaoAluno.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
botaoVerDados.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

raise_frame(telaInicial)
root.mainloop()
```

note: Sorry for the English, its not my mother language.

Comment: put it all in a frame then apply weights around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to place your frame at row and column 1 and then apply weights to column/row 0 and 2. This will keep everything in your frame centered.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
telaInicial = tk.Frame(root)
telaInicial.grid(row=1, column=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

botaoNovoAluno = tk.Button(telaInicial, text="Novo aluno", padx=5, pady=5)
botaoEliminarAluno = tk.Button(telaInicial, text="Eliminar aluno", padx=5, pady=5)
botaoAvaliacaoAluno = tk.Button(telaInicial, text="Avaliaçao aluno", padx=5, pady=5)
botaoVerDados = tk.Button(telaInicial, text="Ver dados", padx=5, pady=5)

botaoNovoAluno.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
botaoEliminarAluno.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
botaoAvaliacaoAluno.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
botaoVerDados.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

That said you may want to take some time to read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Using a standard naming convention will make your code easier to read for everyone.

Comment: Thanks didnt know that!